# alternative for .val() to use it for select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="width">
 <option value="23" selected="selected">10cm</option>
 <option value="26">100cm</option>
 <option value="43">1000cm</option>
</select>
```

I have two similar select options, I am unable to get the value with the .val() function because it will get the id value (23,26,43) I wont to get the 10cm or 100cm or 1000cm.. and then remove the **cm** from the selected value and use that value to multiply with the value of the other select option called height. any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector to get the selected `option` element, once you get the option element you can use [.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to extract the text from it.

```
$('#width option:selected').text()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ygsrv/)

Comment: great I forgot about it, I am so tired of programming I have been programming with PHP for 11 hours now I am wasted and I have deadline :/ I knew about this but my brain is not working so well right now thank you very much, what about removing the cm from the string and converting the number to ingeter?

Comment: .replace(/cm$/, '') I am going to use this to remove the cm from the answer below from Bramar is .toInt going to work I will see

Comment: @TooCooL yes, you can use it

Comment: I made this:
var priceProduct = 18.9
var length = $("#awp_group_5 option:selected").text().replace(/cm$/, '').toInt();
var width = $("#awp_group_4 option:selected").text().replace(/cm$/, '').toInt();
var priceProduct2 = priceProduct + (width * 30 );
 alert(priceProduct2);

and I get: Nan

Comment: I don't think `toInt()` will work, it is not required. test it at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ygsrv/1/

Comment: I tested it in jsfiddle it worked, but for some reason in doesnt work in my project it doesnt replace the cm, maybe it is the problem with cache because the site uses cache system.

Answer (score 1):

```
var width = $("#width option:selected").text().replace(/cm$/, '').toInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript that you need:

```
$(function(){
    $("#width").change(function(){
        var value=$("option:selected").val();
        var text=$("option:selected").text().slice(0,-2);
        alert(value*text);
    });
});
```

to get the selected value use `.val()` and to get the selected text use `text()` of jQuery

After gettting the selected text remove the `cm` using `.slice()` method in jQuery

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2vFM/)